# Using an NSButtonCell with template image in a NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, image, nstableview, nsbutton

In Interface Builder, I have set the dataCell of one of the columns of my NSTableView instance to be NSButtonCell. This works as expected, however, trying to use a ‘template’ image doesn't yield the expected visual result when clicking the button.

How I configure the NSButtonCell:

- Image: NSRevealFreestandingTemplate
- Scaling: None
- Bezel: Bevel
- Type: Momentary Push In
- Bordered: false

Expected result when clicking the button:

- Since the image is a ‘template’, the button should render its ‘on’ state.
- The background, ie the space surrounding the image, should **not** change.

**Actual** result when clicking the button:

- No difference in the ‘state’ of the rendered image.
- The background color changes to white.

Even-though I’ve tried my best to make the explanation of the problem as concise as possible, I’ve also made [a simple screencast](http://superalloy.nl/ImageButtonInTableView/ImageButtonInTableView.mov) to visually illustrate the problem. And uploaded [the demo app](http://superalloy.nl/ImageButtonInTableView/ImageButtonInTableView.zip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the button type to NSMomentaryChangeButton.

Comment: This. I just ran into this problem and tried to use a non-template image to see if that would do it. Turns out I just had to set the Type to "Momentary Change" in IB.

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution turns out to be; **don't** use template images for this…

I decided to show the correct image states myself and discovered that with a non-template image, it works fine.